# Jenkins: schedule slaves activity

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins server with a slave running on a Windows machine that is launched using Java Web Start.
I need this slave to be active only in a certain time frame, for example it must be started every Wednesday at 8.00 pm and must be active for 12 hours.
So I selected "Take this slave online according to a schedule" in the "Schedule" field of the slave configuration, and I entered this expression:
0 20 * * 3
in the "Startup Schedule" field and I set the "Scheduled uptime" to 720 minutes.
I was expecting that all the jobs tied to that slave executed outside the online window would be delayed, put in the queue and started at the specified time.
But if I launch a job tied to that slave, it gets executed even if the slave should be unavailable.
Am I missing something? How can I achieve the behavior I need?

Comment: Was your slave already online when you started your job or did it get started when you started the job?

Comment: On the slave page( /computer/slavename ), I see "Computer has finished its scheduled uptime". So I suppose it is offline. But when I start the job it is immediately run on the slave.

Comment: it should tell you if it is offline or online. Do you have the `disconnect` link in the left hand menu? if so, it is online.

Comment: This is the situation: it' 12:08 now. The slave is online. I configure the slave with this schedule expression: 15 12 * * * and 5 minutes of uptime. I expect the slave to turn off and to come back on in 7 minutes. I save the config, and in the slave page I don't see the Disconnect link. But if I refresh the page, the Disconnect link appear and the slave seems to be on again. If I launch a job tied to that slave, it gets executed. I am really confused.